# jQuery DataTables: asking for wrong no of column's value in IE8

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datatables, ie8-compatibility-mode

It's been a few days since i am using jQuery Datatables and i encounter a problem testing my code on IE8, on IE9 it works fine.

Below is the snapshot of the error i am getting in IE8:
[image: DataTable Warning msg on IE8]

**I go to the link mentioned in this message and i came to know that this error comes when datatables asking for a column value and is getting null or undefined value for that.**

Here's the problem as you can see he is asking for 6th(0 based numbering) column value while i only declare 5 columns and i am sending their values as well.

Below is JQuery portion of datatables initialization:

```
            if (data != null)
            {
                $('#tdUsersTable').html('');
                /*DataTable Implementation*/
                var table = $('#tblUsers').dataTable({
                    "bFilter": true,
                    "bInfo": false,
                    "bDestroy": true,
                    "bwidth": '100%',
                    "sDom": 't',
                    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                    "order": [[0, "asc"]],
                    "aaData": data,
                    "aoColumns": [
                            { "sTitle": "User ID" },
                            { "sTitle": "User Name" },
                            { "sTitle": "User Role" },
                            { "sTitle": "Company" },
                            { "sTitle": "Active" },
                        ],
                    "oLanguage":
                    {
                        "oPaginate":
                     {
                         "sFirst": "   ",
                         "sLast": "   ",
                         "sNext": "   ",
                         "sPrevious": "   "
                     }
                    }
                });
            }
```

I transform my list of data to array and return to JS as JsonResult.
Here is a snapshot of that data:

[image]

And below is the screen shot of data received in JS:

[image]

**Your suggestion are warmly welcome!**

Comment: In almost any case when I have seen this error, the reason is a mismatch between the `<table>` definition and the data. You probably have a table with 5 `<th>`'s but import data with only 4 columns. A qualified guess, but cant really tell. We dont know the table markup or the content of data. Looking at the screenshots, it looks like each row is enveloped in some kind of markup (`<span>`'s)?

Comment: I paste all the code but somehow table html not copied, anyway here is the table html:
$('#tdUsersTable').html('<table id="tblUsers" rules="all" style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid #808080;"></table>');

Comment: as you can see i am not defining the columns headers or rows, i let the column creation to plugin.@davidkonrad

Comment: mvc is hell good @ZeeshanAjmal..:D

Comment: @ZeeshanAjmal how are you able to debug js using VS quick watch

Comment: @EhsanSajjad pehle issue solve kr phir btaon ga :)

Comment: @EhsanSajjad yr IE ko use krte huay kia ha. Run the site, go to script tab, click "start capturing", add a break point in js, execute the process, jb us line pe aey ga to execution stop ho jaey gi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surprisingly answer was very simple, when i came to know it i was shocked.
Above code raises error due to the **trailing comma**, yes that was the problem.

**IE 9** is fairly intelligent, when it sees that there are no **title** after last comma it ignores it but when it came to **IE 8** it interprets that if there is a **comma** at the end, there should have to be a column, and if it did't i will try to make one by itself :)

In order to avoid this error you just have to remove the **trailing comma**, that is after **Active** as displayed below:

```
                  "aoColumns": [
                        { "sTitle": "User ID" },
                        { "sTitle": "User Name" },
                        { "sTitle": "User Role" },
                        { "sTitle": "Company" },
                        { "sTitle": "Active" }
                    ],
```